# How much money does it take to pump a stock/crypto currency?

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-markets, cryptocurrency

Like for example, if a stock is worth $0.10, how much would it take to actually have an effect on the price, even if it only goes up $0.01 cent, how much would it take to change the price? Same for a crypto currency, such as like shibu inu which is like $0.0000006

Comment: If you're an eccentric billionaire with a lot of followers - one tweet?

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot more on the volume and the size of the order book than on the price.

For a penny stock that sees 0 shares traded most days and has no outstanding orders, you could pump the stock up for a few dollars.  Buy 1 share at $0.10 the first day, 1 share at $0.20 the second day, $0.35 the third day, etc.  If no one else is bidding, you could get a nice, steeply increasing price graph pretty cheaply.  Of course, if you're a scammer, you'd actually want to accumulate more than a handful of shares at this phase of the "pump".  You'd then try to convince others to buy (i.e. touting the share price has tripled in the past few days and is poised to go higher).  And then once you got some suckers trying to buy up all the shares they can, you dump your shares at the high price and hope that the SEC doesn't come a-knocking.

For something that thousands of people are actively trading, regardless of the current price, it would be a lot more expensive to change the price just through market orders.  If you wanted to triple the price of the token, you'd need to buy all the tokens anyone was offering for a price less than $0.0000018.  That would be a whole lot of people selling a whole lot of tokens and would cost quite a lot.  For something like this with more volume, it would be a lot cheaper (and probably easier) to hype up the asset to convince the people already in the market that it was going to increase.